# The legend colors are not perfectly similar to color of polygons

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, legend

I am using the leaflet function to create an interactive map within the shiny framework. Everything looks great except the legend. The colors of the legend are somewhat faded and therefore not perfectly represent the colors of polygons. How can this be solved?

[image]

```
    renderLeaflet ({

    pal8 <- c("#FFFFE5", "#D9F0A3", "#78C679", "#006837") 
  bins=quantile(mapdata_1()$Per), na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F)
   pal <- colorFactor(palette = pal8, domain =NULL, levels=(mapdata_1()$cat), ordered = TRUE, na.color = "#808080",  alpha = FALSE, reverse = F)

     leaflet (mapdata_()) %>% 

                      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
                     clearControls() %>%
                     clearShapes()%>%
                        addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(cat)) %>% 



                                   addTiles() %>%

      setView(-82.706838, 40.358615, zoom=7) %>%

                        addLegend(position = "bottomright",
                         values = ~cat,

                         pal = pal,
                         title = (paste("%",input$Age_Group_map, input$sex_map, "in", input$Year_map)) ,
                       labFormat = labelFormat(
                      ))

        })
```

Comment: It looks like part of the problem is the legend is transparent, what happens when you set `opacity = 1.0` in `addLegend`?

Comment: It perfectly worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend is transparent by default, which affects the appearance of the colours. Change the `opacity` argument to fix this:

```
addLegend(position = "bottomright",
          values = ~cat, 
          pal = pal,
          opacity = 1.0,
          title = (paste("%",input$Age_Group_map, 
                         input$sex_map, "in", input$Year_map)) ,
          labFormat = labelFormat())
```